# Latitude/Longitude lookup during a csv-import

Tags: php, google-maps

how can i get lat-/longitude of an address during an CSV-Import by PHP? I import addresses from a csv and save these into a mysql-table. During the import i've to verify the latitude/longitude of the adresse to save this information into the table too.

Code:

```
    while ( ($data = fgetcsv ($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE ) { 
    …

    $adress = urlencode($data[4]).",".$data[5]."+".$data['6'];
    $geocode=file_get_contents("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".$adress."&sensor=false");
    $output= json_decode($geocode);

    $lat = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
    $lng = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->png;

    …
    }
```

Error-Info: file_get_contents(http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Im+Chr%E4merhoger+10,8910+Affoltern am Albis&sensor=false) [function.file-get-contents.php]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in

Thanks for help/tips.

regards
thomas

Comment: How could anyone ever know? Without a code example, demonstrating what you are doing, it is impossible to answer.  I use a lot of importing of lat/lng's from CSV to MySQL myself, but I wouldnt dare to answer without knowing what you are trying to do, precisely.

Comment: hi, just added my code...

Comment: +1, upvoted your question just for that! :)

Comment: `$lng = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->**png**;` ??

Comment: Think you must urlencode your request. There is a few blanks that needs to be turned into `%20`s

Comment: [No Pre-Fetching, Caching, or Storage of Content](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_1_3)

Answer (score 0):

try to change [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.urlencode.php) into [rawurlencode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php)